# Phonegap Android splash screen not showing up

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

I am making an app in phonegap android and want to add Splash Screen to my app. I read various tutorials and the official documentation and **tried the following**:

Adding these lines to my `config.xml` (present outside and NOT inside `../platforms/android/res/xml`

```
<platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="platforms/android/res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.9.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="platforms/android/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.9.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="platforms/android/res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.9.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="platforms/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.9.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

Here `screen.9.png` is the file that I have pasted in these folders (appropriate dimensions). Please note that there is no other file in these directory.

Then I built the project and it succeeded but splash screen didn't show up on my phone. Any reason where I am going wrong?

***********************EDIT********************************************

I even tried this:

```
<platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="b.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="d.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="c.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="a.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

It built without any error but the splash screen did not show up even in this case. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to put the images in to somewhere else than under `platforms/` folder, for example on the root of your whole project to see if it has any effect? I wouldn't anyway locate them under platforms, instead I'd create a `res/` under root of project. Also, there is no point creating separate folder for each density, instead rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

Put these configuration options on your *config.xml* outside the `<platform name="android">` (like other configuration options)

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

and make sure you have the *b.png* etc. on your root folder, in the same level as where the *www*, *platforms*, *hooks* etc. are.